# Can we make a scanf like function that returns true when all parameters are populated and false otherwise without looping through all variables?

Tags: c++, c, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, variadic

I would like to do this in C++ (or C if required).  I looking into Variadic Functions and the only method I could come up with seemed rather poor in terms of performance:

```
scanner(const char * string, const char * format, ...) // ... is the variables
{
  bool got_them_all(false);
  size_t length_of_list(0);
  va_list variables_list;
  va_start(variables_list, format);
  // Loop through variables_list and count until we run out of items
  ...
  if (length_of_list == sscanf(string, format, va_list))
  {
    got_them_all = true;
  }
  va_end(variables_list);
  return got_them_all;
}
```

In my specific use case these are command parameters coming in and I know the string format.  What I am trying to do is avoid errors where I count 5 parameters but pass scanf (OK really sscanf in my case) 4 or 5.  I would call the function with: 
  `allOK = scanner(command_cstring, "CMD:%02d,%02d", inta, intb);`
Now in that case I can easily see that there are 2 parameters so I could do the `if (2 = scanner(command_cstring, "CMD:%02d,%02d", inta, intb));` reliably.  When it is more than half a dozen parameters I think my odds of not getting something wrong get rather high.

I would rather not add a loop to count parameters to my dynamic incoming string processing.  It sounds like a waste of CPU time on this small embedded system.

There seems no standard way to do sizeof(va_list).

Variadic Templates sound hopeful.  I don't mind the compile time computing load as at that point the code has the longest list of variables I am going to enter.  I do not have a C++11 compiler available for me, but I would be happy to accept a solution that needed one for the future.  If I had a C++11 option today then I would probably be trying to get something together myself right now.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to tell at runtime how many arguments are passed to a varargs function. Nor can you tell what the types of the arguments are. In short, it is your responsibility to get it right.

However, if you are using gcc or clang and your format strings are literal strings, then the compiler will warn you if there is a mismatch between the format string and the number or types of the arguments. This warning is enabled with `-Wformat`, but it is also one of the many useful warnings enabled with `-Wall`. (If you are compiling without `-Wall`, you are effectively wearing a blindfold.)

Comment: I definatly have -Wformat enabled.  Messages such as  `: warning: format '%x' expects argument of type 'unsigned int*', but argument 4 has type 'long int' [-Wformat=]` have already been correcting my poor typing.  Nice to know that i might get a warning if the string and variables don't align, that is one less silent error I can make.

Comment: @TafT: You should certainly get a warning if there are too few or too many arguments for the format string. Try it and see. You might want to specify `-Werror=format`, which will turn those warnings into errors making them even harder to ignore.

Comment: Seems to warn when I have too many variables, but not too few `warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]`.  I suppose too few is undefined behaviour so a warning might be inappropriate.

Comment: @TafT: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bde4b1bacb92573a shows warnings for too few arguments. (Although the message could be confused with a type mismatch, it's certainly not inaccurate.) As is often the case, clang has better error messages: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b782d013ceb5f74

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class...Ts>
bool scanner(const char * string, const char * format, Ts const&...ts)
{
  size_t num_scanned = sscanf(string, format, ts...);
  bool got_them_all = num_scanned == sizeof...(ts);
  return got_them_all;
}
```

would do it.  Note, however, that if you specify more parameters in the string than you pass, you'll do undefined behavior within `sscanf`.

Annoying, you'll want to scan `format` for the format specifiers yourself prior to calling `sscanf` to make it safe.  At least do this in a debug build.

Comment: Yakk, I think what you have suggested will do exactly what I need.  When combined with the warnings that @rici mention it covers most of the mistakes that I can make.

Comment: That is a shame, it seems that gcc 4.8.4 does not produce the Wformat and Wformat-extra-args warnings when things are passed through the template.  I suppose I am thinking of things as if they were defines getting expanded, still feels like it should be able to check it.  I see now why Yakk said I need to parse format.

Comment: After asking about this on a GCC users mailing list someone pointed me at the compilers __attribute__ feature that lets you tell GCC to check a function as if it was a printf/scanf,etc.  The only problem is that it cannot support variadic functions so I have to pass things through a VARGS to have the checks triggered. There is some #define switching you can do to add it in debug and not in standard. Look for `__attribute__((format(scanf, blah blah)))` in https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2015-11/msg00127.html for more background.